SQL Server database size is 10GB but tables are only around 450MB, what is occupying the rest and how can I reduce it?
I have a SQL Server database that has reached the 10 GB limit.
When I do use EXEC sp_spaceused, I get



reserved
data
index_size
unused




10483208 KB
10352336 KB
90264 KB
40608 KB



However when I do this query:
SELECT 
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM
    sys.tables t
JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id

I get that the sum of the tables barely is 450 MB.
I've started getting this error when doing some procedures:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not allocate space for object 'sys.change_tracking_517680992' .'sys_change_cidx' from database '***' because filegroup 'PRIMARY' is full. Delete unnecessary files, remove objects from the filegroup, add additional files to the filegroup, or set the auto-growth option for existing files in the filegroup to create disk space.

So I guess it's logs or tracking files that are taking up the remaining space? Can I delete them somehow?

Based on error message the space could be taken by Change Tracking
Do you have it enabled? Do you have Auto cleanup configured? What is retention_period? Is it something you are expected?
Check in sys.change_tracking_databases
If your problem related to change tracking here are some troubleshooting

Thank you! Change Tracking Auto Cleanup was set to False, I've changed it to True. This solved my problem.

Did you run the "Disk Usage by Table" report in SSMS?  It runs this query:
SELECT
    (row_number() over(order by a3.name, a2.name))%2 as l1,
    a3.name AS [schemaname],
    a2.name AS [tablename],
    a1.rows as row_count,
    (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0))* 8 AS reserved, 
    a1.data * 8 AS data,
    (CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS index_size,
    (CASE WHEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) > a1.used THEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) - a1.used ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS unused
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ps.object_id,
        SUM (
            CASE
                WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN row_count
                ELSE 0
            END
            ) AS [rows],
        SUM (ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
        SUM (
            CASE
                WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN (ps.in_row_data_page_count + ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
                ELSE (ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
            END
            ) AS data,
        SUM (ps.used_page_count) AS used
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
        WHERE ps.object_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE is_memory_optimized = 1)
    GROUP BY ps.object_id) AS a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        it.parent_id,
        SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
        SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS used
     FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
     INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON (it.object_id = ps.object_id)
     WHERE it.internal_type IN (202,204)
     GROUP BY it.parent_id) AS a4 ON (a4.parent_id = a1.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects a2  ON ( a1.object_id = a2.object_id ) 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas a3 ON (a2.schema_id = a3.schema_id)
WHERE a2.type <> N'S' and a2.type <> N'IT'
ORDER BY a3.name, a2.name

